# Altitudes of a triangle

Tags: geometry

I want to know if you can help me with a problem of geometry. If I have a scalene triangle and its three altitudes, how can I show that only one altitude is longer than the respective orthogonal base?.
Thanks

Comment: I think this is not true in general...take an equilateral triangle, all the altitudes are less than the respective orthogonal bases.

Comment: You are right, for an equilateral triangle the three altitudes have the same length and this magnitude is less than the magnitude of the side. Thanks for your answer. I will edit my question for a scalene triangle.

Comment: The issue remains. If you take an almost equilateral triangle, with side lengths, say, $99,100,101$, every altitude is still shorter than the corresponding side.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your answer. So this is not true in general.